# What is the relationship between tflearn and tf.contrib.learn?

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

What is the relationship between [`tflearn`](http://tflearn.org/) and [`tf.contrib.learn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tflearn)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both, `tflearn` and `tf.contrib.learn` are abstractions from pure Tensorflow.

When you look at the Github projects ([tflearn](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn) and [tf.contrib.learn](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn)) you can compare them a bit:

```
              tflearn        tf.contrib.learn
-------------------------------------------------
origins                      skflow (Scikit Flow)
first commit  31.05.2016     19.04.2016 (?)
commits       549            853 (*1)
contributors  91             39 (*2)
```

While `tf.contrib.learn` describes itself as a "High level API for learning" and contains linear and logistic regression, kmeans, ... it does not offer a convolutional layer, for example. `tf.contrib.learn` aims to have a similar interface to `scikit-learn`.

In contrast, `tflearn` describes itself as a "a modular and transparent deep learning library built on top of Tensorflow". It contains all basic deep learning building blocks.

### Methods

- `*1`: `git log --pretty=format:"%h" . | wc -l`
- `*2`: `git log --pretty=format:"%an" . | sort | uniq | wc -l`

### More, similar packages

- By Google:

  - PrettyTensor
  - TF-Slim
- 3rd party:

  - [TensorLayer](http://tensorlayer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
  - [sugartensor](https://github.com/buriburisuri/sugartensor)
  - Keras